# Pressing Alt+Left/Right causes screen flicker

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, kernel

I run Arch Linux with a "normal" Xorg desktop, that is, using LightDM as login manager and the i3 Window Manager (with some components from Xfce, GNOME and KDE as needed). The graphics is the integrated Intel graphics from my i7-4770T processor.

Since some time ago, it happens that whenever I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or any of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F10</kbd> key combinations, the screen flickers shortly. The action I wanted to do (e.g. go back in the browser history) is executed, but the screen flickers.

I have a suspicion that the kernel key bindings for changing the VT are executed, i.e. the VT changes, Xorg is notified and will display on the new VT.

I have tried adding

```
Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
```

and

```
Option "XKbOptions" "srvrkeys:none"
```

to my `xorg.conf` in the appropriate places, and I can see them being accepted, but neither changes the describes behaviour.

Comment: My suspicion is that this has something to do with the desktop switcher. Check if it's enabled on your setup, and see also [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1860889&page=2&p=12219484#post12219484) (although for Ubuntu).

Comment: What is a desktop switcher? I don't have compiz or similar installed.

Comment: I'm not using i3, but it seems according to the User's Guide that the $mod+arrow keys are used for changing the focus. You might need to disable these key combinations.

Comment: Thanks, but my $mod is the Windows key (mod4), not Alt.

Comment: You might consider adding some more information about your setup to the post.

Comment: @harrymc what would you say is missing? I cannot list all the software that I do *not* have installed...

Comment: For example your computer model and keyboard, Linux version and the versions of all software that could be connected to the problem. Add as much as you can - it's not normal that you didn't yet get any feedback to your post except mine.

Comment: Now you have more visibility, but this didn't help to guess which is your problem. Some shots in the darkness: 1. new graphic accelerations setting, 2 updated graphic drivers, 3 new version of the program/plug in you are using... are _The Usual Suspects_,  of course occurred  _"since __that__ some time ago"_  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as it was the same case [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/438557) and [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-797010-start-0.html), after several months of this annoyance, the latest system upgrade fixed it (I upgrade every couple of days, so it must have been a recent fix). Whatever it was causing it, it is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a solution, I did some digging & found these two solutions which worked for me -

1. from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1066803/1038200)

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

2. and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186016)

```
sudo sh -c 'dumpkeys |grep -v cr_Console |loadkeys'
```

PS: the second method seems to be a more permanent fix.